# M2.2.2 development site has error

Tags: magento2, admin

I had been doing some work on my development site and the next day the error displayed in the screenshot showed. I also cannot navigate away from this page. How do I fix this?

Error Message "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later." on Account Information screen

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the Developer Console, Console and Network tabs, for more information and please share that with us. Edit: I see you are on a mobile platform. I'd look at this on a desktop version of Chrome and share the additional details I mentioned.

Comment: I updated the question. The network tab appears normal.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a similar case relating to users and the "A technical problem with the server created an error" message on ([Ref GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10071)). The solution was to ensure that all admin users had privileges assigned to them via **System** > **Permissions** > **User Roles**